# Can I move the sort arrow of an SWT table to the right instead of on top?

Tags: java, swt

Is there any way to move the sort arrow from an SWT table to the right of a column header rather than on top?

I know you can get rid of the arrow by not setting the image:

```
table.setSortDirection(sortAscending ? SWT.UP : SWT.DOWN);
```

but I haven't seen any way to move the sort indicator. Is there a way I haven't seen?

Sort indicator on top:

[image: Sort indicator on top]

Sort indicator on the side:

[image: Sort indicator on the side]

Comment: I have edited your question and have removed the [tag:jtable] tag as I am quite sure that this refers to the Swing component of the same name and not to any SWT component. Please do correct me and comment back to me if I am wrong in this.

Comment: Where is "on top"? Can you maybe add a mockup of what you would like to see?

Comment: What you call "on top" is the default arrow (sort indicator) position on Windows 7 (possibly 8?). It may be (and indeed will be) different on another OS and even other versions. AFAIK, there is no way to influence the sort indicator position.

Comment: Yeah - I'm running Windows 7. I didn't find anything either. Oh well. I guess this is part of SWT trying to be "native"?

Comment: @chama Well, how the widgets look like is actually not up to SWT. They are rendered by the OS.